# can't update text fields in a UIViewController that pushed onto a UINavigation Controller

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a UINavigationController that gets UIViewControllers pushed onto it.  In the first view there is a grouped table view which has 3 rows, each containing a UITextField with initial text set on viewWillLoad of that view controller.  Tapping any one of the table view cells pushes the 2nd UIViewController onto the nav controller's stack.  Each of the secondary view controllers has another table view where the user can select a choice by touching one of the rows.

The experience is identical to the iPhone's ical, when selecting "repeat" for an event.

The problem is that when the user touches the UIBarButtonItem to save, and I set the selected value into the previous views text field, the text field doesn't update.  Regardles of what text I set it doesn't update when the navigation controller pops back to the first view.  Could it be cached, or the view cached as a whole?

I'm logging all the values and everything looks correct.

Sorry to not post any code, I'm not sure how to without posting a book.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a reloadData when the main view reappears. This forces the table to refetch the visible rows and redraw them.

```
[theTable reloadData];
```

Edit: an improvement would be to only reload the row affected, instead of reloading all the visible rows with the reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: method.